# DataTable - Serverside - sort columns initialisation

Tags: datatable, datatables, configuration, server-side-rendering

I have 6 datatables with one datatable configuration on a page with a basic layout as follows for all five tables:

```
 <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>COL_1</th>
         <th>COL_2</th>
         <th>COL_1</th>
         <th>COL_1</th>
         <th>COL_1</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr><td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

and my datatable configuration options is as below:

```
     {
         order: [[5, "desc"], [2, "asc"]]
         .......
     }
```

My issue is I need to order by columns by table. For example, in table 1, I would like to order columns 1 and 4 for second table on columns 3 and 4 and third on columns 0 and 3 etc., Is there a way to do that without having six different configurations for each datatable?

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize the DataTable initialization code - to a certain extent.

As an example, assume the following three simple tables:

```
    $('#example1').DataTable( {
        "paging":   true,
        "order": [[5, desc"], [2, "asc"]]
    } );

    $('#example2').DataTable( {
        "paging":   true,
        "order": [[2, "asc"], [3, "asc"]]
    } );

    $('#example3').DataTable( {
        "paging":   true,
        "order": [[4, "asc"], [2, "desc"]]
    } );
```

The only parts which differ from table to table are:

- the table name
- the default sort order

We can extract these differences into a JavaScript object and then iterate over it as follows:

```
    var configs = [
        { 
           tableName: 'example1',
           order: [[5, "desc"], [2, "asc"]] 
        },
        { 
           tableName: 'example2',
           order: [[2, "asc"], [3, "asc"]] 
        },
        { 
           tableName: 'example3',
           order: [[4, "asc"], [2, "desc"]] 
        }
      ];

    configs.forEach( function ( config ) {
        console.log(config.tableName);

        $('#' + config.tableName).DataTable( {
            "paging":   true,
            "order": config.order
        } );

    } );
```

The end result is the same as the three separate table definitions.

You can, of course add more data to the `config` object, such as a source URL, and so on. There may be some configuration items which cannot be handled in this way - for example, nested functions. It depends on how complex you need your table initialization to be.

It's a judgement call as to whether this is worth doing, in your case. There is a loss of readability, which needs to be considered.